# Cierre de threads en python

Tags: python, hilos

Mi script lanza cada X minutos una serie de tareas de revisión que pueden o no realizar ciertas acciones. Al mismo tiempo que se lanzan estas tareas, hay otra principal ejecutándose a modo de monitor y mostrando por pantalla información.

Me he dado cuenta que el consumo de memoria RAM del script, poco a poco va creciendo durante el paso de los días y me temo que pueda ser debido a los threads, que los abro pero al finalizar la tarea se quedan abiertos y siguen consumiendo recursos aunque en realidad no estén haciendo nada.

No estoy segura de que esto sea así, pero en cualquier caso lanzo la duda y os pongo el código que tengo ahora mismo:

Definición de una función para ejecutar Threads:

```
def run_threaded(function_name):

    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_name)
    job_thread.start()
```

Un schedule para lanzar la función cada hora

```
schedule.every(1).hours.at("30:05").do(run_threaded,count_files)
```

Y luego la función count_files, que como su nombre indica, simplemente cuenta ficheros, no creo que sea relevante el código en si mismo.

Y ahora la pregunta final. He visto que con un `return` se pueden cerrar los threads, pero dónde?
Porque si pongo el `return` en la función `run_threaded` o bien en la función `count_files` realmente estoy devolviendo un valor (en este caso entiendo que None puesto que no retorno una variable), pero no estaría cerrando el thread en sí mismo.

Comment: Usualmente con las herramientas de tu sistema operativo (task manager, ps, etc) puedes ver cuántos hilos están en ejecución dentro de cada proceso. Antes de seguir sospechando de los hilos, puedes confirmar que la cuenta solo sube y nunca baja cada hora? ¿si estás segura que la rutina count_files termina alguna vez y no se queda ciclada?